# Bind generated REST service interface implementation to servlet

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey, jersey-client

I have got a `wadl` file from which I'm generating objects and interfaces for the `REST`services with the `wadl2java` tool. I have implementations for these interfaces and all is fine so far. I have also configured the `servlet` in the `web.xml` but I just can´t get this to work. For now my web xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>com.foo.ws.RestServiceImpl</param-value>               
        </init-param>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The generated rest interface looks like following:

```
package com.foo.schemas;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import com.foo.schemas.BarRequest;
import com.foo.schemas.BarResponse;
import com.foo.schemas.FooRequest;
import com.foo.schemas.FooResponse;

@Path("services")
public interface RestService {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    BarResponse getBar(BarRequest barRequest);

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    FooResponse getFoo(FooRequest fooRequest);
}
```

And it's implementation:

```
package com.foo.ws;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import com.foo.RestService;
import com.foo.schemas.BarRequest;
import com.foo.schemas.BarResponse;
import com.foo.schemas.FooRequest;
import com.foo.schemas.FooResponse;

public class RestServiceImpl extends ResourceConfig implements RestService {
    public RestServiceImpl () {
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(RestServiceImpl.class).to(RestService.class);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    BarResponse getBar(BarRequest barRequest) {
        // Implementation omitted...
    }

    @Override
    FooResponse getFoo(FooRequest FooRequest) {
        // Implementation omitted...
    }
}
```

I think this looks fine but when I'm starting the web service I get following `HTTP ERROR 503`:

```
Problem accessing /my-web-service/. Reason:

org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of    
the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP 
method POST and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" 
annotations at Java methods public com.foo.schemas.BarResponse 
com.foo.ws.RestServiceImpl.getBar(com.foo.schemas.BarRequest) and public 
com.foo.schemas.FooResponse 
com.foo.ws.RestServiceImpl.getFoo(com.foo.schemas.FooRequest) at matching 
regular expression /services. These two methods produces and consumes 
exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource 
methods will always fail.; 
source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@5690c2a8'
```

It looks like the binding between the interface and implementation is correct but I don't really understand why I get this error? Yes the methods are defined with the same `MIME-types`  for both the `@Consumes` and `@Produces` annotations but this is how `wadl2java` generated the interface? I have no idea how to solve this, are there any configuration errors for the servlet or wadl2java tool? I have not a clue, any help in this is really appreciated as I'm stuck with this one.

EDIT - Added wadl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:foo="http://schemas.foo.com" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02    http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/wadl.xsd" 
         xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
<doc xml:lang="en">This wadl describes....</doc>
<grammars>
    <include href="foo.xsd"/>
</grammars>
<resources base="/foo">
    <resource path="services">
        <method id="getBar" name="POST">
            <doc xml:lang="en">Get all bars.</doc>
            <request>
                <representation mediaType="application/xml">
                    <param required="true" style="plain" id="barRequest" name="barRequest" type="foo:BarRequest"/>
                </representation>
            </request>
            <response status="200">
                <representation mediaType="application/xml">
                    <param required="true" style="plain" id="barResponse" name="barResponse" type="foo:BarResponse"/>
                </representation>
            </response>
        </method>
        <method id="getFoo" name="POST">
            <doc xml:lang="en">Get all foos.</doc>
            <request>
                <representation mediaType="application/xml">
                    <param required="true" style="plain" id="fooRequest" name="fooRequest" type="foo:FooRequest"/>
                </representation>
            </request>
            <response status="200">
                <representation mediaType="application/xml">
                    <param required="true" style="plain" id="fooResponse" name="fooResponse" type="foo:FooResponse"/>
                </representation>
            </response>
        </method>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is w.r.t how the resources are exposed.

1. There are 2 POST Method's exposed, both listening to path "**/services**".
2. Both these methods Consume and Produce the **same MimeType**.

**The problem** - is if this resource is hit. Then Jersey would not understand which API to invoke in order to get the result.
Is it getBar() or getFoo()

Now, the change depends on what the expectation is (which & when an API needs to be invoked, based on the requirement).
You'll have to modify the WADL accordingly to make sure each resource listens to a unique path/consume/produce type.

```
@Path("services")
public interface RestService {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    BarResponse getBar(BarRequest barRequest);

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    FooResponse getFoo(FooRequest fooRequest);
}
```

Comment: Okey, I understand the issues and explanations of them that you give. I have also tested now by removing all the methods except one and annotate each methods with it's own path and both of these scenarios works. What I then think is strange is that I have been given this WADL file from some consultants and it should be ready to use, but as you describe and what I think this WADL isn't fully complete as wadl2java produces interfaces like this. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: @Robert yes, that's right. The WADL file appears to be wrong. Is it possible for you to upload just this part of the code from WADL file where these services are defined? Also, I don't think WADL parser that validate/parse the document would treat this as an error. Because for WADL, all it needs is what is the current resource able to provide, rather than checking what other resources may also provide and whether they conflict with one another. In any case the WADL document needs to get updated.

Comment: I added the WADL file to the question now. Also one other thing I really don't understand. If the WADL file is wrong how can it come that an import of it in SoapUI works without a hitch, with paths and so on?

Comment: @Robert Because you can still have 2 different functions with the same Path but Different RequestMethods.
For Example, you can implement getFoo as GET and getBar as POST. This is perfectly valid.
Since these are validation's that jersey/spring needs to take care. In fact in Spring it is valid to give 2 methods same path and Method but by providing params attribute in the method. So as WADL needs to support different services, it cannot have logic to verify these. Again, this is IMO.

Comment: @Robert Yes, the WADL is defined wrongly. This wouldn't work. You'll have to check with the provider to change the contract a little.

Comment: Rewrote the WADL file with paths to each methods and now it's working correctly, thanks!